# What is the ISO 639x Value for Dutch?

Tags: delphi, localization, iso-639

Our program uses the ISO 639x code to name the language files easily.

However, in https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Language_Culture_Names,_Codes,_and_ISO_Values, the code for Dutch - The Netherlands is empty. How to find the correct code?

THanks

Update

I finally create a new project in Delphi XE3, then select "Language" and try to add a new language, the following box will show all the code for all languages, including Dutch Netherlands:

[image]

Comment: That's because Dutch isn't a language - it's a throat disease (running, ducking for cover :-) )

Comment: @HeartWare, but there is a code for "Dutch - Belgium", it is NLB.

Comment: No @HeartWare you are referring to Danish (following close behind in zig zag :D)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) the ISO 639-x codes for `Dutch, Flemish` (is that the one you're looking for?) are:

> | 639-1 | 639-2/T | 639-2/B | 639-3 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `nl` | `nld` | `dut` | `nld` |
>
> Flemish is not to be confused with the closely related [West Flemish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Flemish) which is referred to as *Vlaams* (Dutch for "Flemish") in ISO 639-3 and has the [ISO 639-3 code `vls`](https://iso639-3.sil.org/code/vls)

Comment: But according to the linked embarcadero page there is a code for Dutch-Belgium : NLB but that doesn't exist in the wiki page. This is strange.

Comment: I suppose that list is [just a remix from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/commerce-server/ee825488(v=cs.20)) and `NLB` is no official ISO 639 value, because 1.) it's in uppercase (languages are always in lowercase) and 2.) it is[n't listed as change to the list](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_changes.php) ever.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the value - it is `LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME` as per [Learn / Windows / Apps / Win32 / Desktop Technologies / Desktop App User Interface / Internationalization / LOCALE_SABBREV* Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-sabbrev-constants):

> Abbreviated name of the language. In most cases, the name is created by taking the two-letter language abbreviation from ISO Standard 639 and adding a third letter, as appropriate, to indicate the sublanguage. For example, the abbreviated name for the language corresponding to the English (United States) locale is ENU.

```
// $0413 is the locale ID for Dutch
TmpStr := GetLocaleStr($0413, LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME, '');  // return 'NLD'
```